# Magento2 catalog search issue

Tags: magento2

Magento2 catalog search on frontend does not retrieve exact search. if i want to search fulltext, there is no option.

please guide me how to print full query and how to change of this query?

Comment: You should describe in more details what you have tried so far and what exactly the problem is.

Comment: What is Magento version ?

Comment: magento version 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to search attributes such as description, make sure to enable it by going to Stores > Attributes > Product
Click on attribute > Storefront Properties > Use in Search, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

you should enable search section of attributes that you want to search such as description,name, sku make sure to enable it by going to Stores > Attributes > Product Click on attribute > Storefront Properties > Use in Search, Yes.